# multiple field autosuggest in primefaces

Tags: primefaces

i need to know can i implement the multiple field autosuggest like ice faces in primefaces.. jsf!
http://www.imagehousing.com/imageupload.php?id=625518

Answer (score 0):

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/autoCompleteMultiple.jsf